# Creating the index over a non pk column in phoenix-sqlline

Tags: indexing, hbase

I am using phoenix-sqlline over hbase tables. I have multiple tables out of which one is a metadata table. The primary key of the metadata table is used in all other tables to fetch the metadata. The query involves JOIN over this pk on metadata table and other tables

```
metadata_table (pk, mcol1,mcol2..)  // primary key is pk

table1(pk1, pk,t1col1,t1col2..)// primary key is pk1

table2(pk2, pk,t2col1,t2col2..)// primary key is pk2

SELECT a.pk,a.mcol1, b.t1col1,b.t1col2
FROM metadata_table a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.pk=b.pk
WHERE a.pk IN('a','b');
```

The number of rows in all those tables is ~2 million. So I thought I will create index on pk column in table1 as pk on metadata_table is already indexed.

```
CREATE INDEX pkindex ON table1, pk

SELECT /*+ USE_SORT_MERGE_JOIN, INDEX(table1 pkindex)*/ 
a.pk,a.mcol1, b.t1col1,b.t1col2
FROM metadata_table a
INNER JOIN table1 b ON a.pk=b.pk
WHERE a.pk IN('a','b');
```

The query works. But like table1, table2 I have n tables and creating indexes for them and forming the query dynamically based on the request becomes challenging.